# Não esta criando com o "persist"

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] in context with path [/cq] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call] with root cause
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:277)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.persist(Unknown Source)
    at br.portoseguro.cq.dao.AreaDAO.criarNovaArea(AreaDAO.java:20)
    at br.portoseguro.cq.service.AreaService.criarNovaArea(AreaService.java:25)
    at br.portoseguro.cq.controller.ManterCadastrosController.criarNovaArea(ManterCadastrosController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Classe controller:

```
package br.teste.cq.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import br.teste.cq.entity.Area;
import br.teste.cq.service.AreaService;

@Transactional
@Controller
public class ManterCadastrosController {

    private AreaService areaService;

    @Autowired
    public ManterCadastrosController(AreaService areaService) {
        this.areaService = areaService;
    }


    @RequestMapping("CriarArea")
    public String criarNovaArea(Area area, BindingResult result, Model model) throws IOException {
        area = areaService.criarNovaArea(area);
        model.addAttribute("area", area);
        return "";
    }



}
```

Classe service:

```
package br.teste.cq.service;

import java.io.IOException;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import br.teste.cq.dao.AreaDAO;
import br.teste.cq.entity.Area;

@Service
public class AreaService {

    private AreaDAO dao;

    @Autowired
    public AreaService(AreaDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public Area criarNovaArea(Area area) throws IOException {
        return dao.criarNovaArea(area);
    }
}
```

Classe AreaDAO:

```
package br.teste.cq.dao;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import br.teste.cq.entity.Area;

@Repository
public class AreaDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager manager;


    public Area criarNovaArea(Area area) throws IOException {
        manager.persist(area);
        return area;
    }

}
```

DataSource:

```
<bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd"></property>
    <property name="username" value="usuario"></property>
    <property name="password" value="senha"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Olá! Consegue compartilhar o código do AreaDAO?

Comment: @Dherik adicionado

Comment: Tenta remover o @Transactional do Controller e passar ele para o AreaService, veja se muda algo. Você está usando Spring Boot? Pode ser problema de configuração

Comment: @Dherik mesma coisa

Comment: Você configurou o DataSource como? Pode ser problema de configuração. É a primeira vez no seu projeto que está tentando persistir algo no banco?

Comment: @Dherik, peguei as configurações de um projeto anterior que esta funcionando normal.

Sim, é a primeira vez que vou inserir algo no banco.

Comment: Tenta verificar se não esqueceu algo relacionado a configuração do DataSource (conexão com o banco de dados), eu suspeito que o problema esteja nele. Se possível, compartilhe este código.

Comment: Você pode postar a classe do seu projeto que contém o `main() `? Isso é provavelmente um problema de configuração para suportar transações.

Comment: @StatelessDev não tenho uma classe que contenha o metodo main(), só estou testando a gravação de dados no banco, teria alguma outra classe que foge das que adicionei acima?

Irei colocar o dataSource também.

Comment: Você deve ter uma classe anotada com @SpringBootApplication. É o entry point de uma aplicação Spring.

Comment: @StatelessDev, não era isso. Estava faltando a tag <tx:annotation-driven /> no spring-context.

resolvido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estava faltando a seguinte tag no arquivo spring-context:

E mais algumas configurações no XML

http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

XML ANTES:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="br.projeto.cq" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

XML DEPOIS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" **xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx // ADICIONADO ESSA CONFIG //**"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        **http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  // ADICIONADO ESSA CONFIG ///** **http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd //ADICIONADO ESSA CONFIG //**">
    <context:component-scan base-package="br.projeto.cq" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />             /////// ADICIONADO ESTA LINHA
</beans>
```

Comment: Se você puder postar como estava seu XML antes e depois das suas correções seria muito útil para programadores que sofressem desse mesmo problema e encontrassem sua resposta no futuro.

Comment: @StatelessDev adicionado meu caro, um abraço.